# how to use group by LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to show the company name with each number of employees (count of persons).

```
var result2 = (from c in NoOfEntities.listOfCompanies
               join s in NoOfEntities.listOfStores on c.Id equals s.CompanyId
               join p in NoOfEntities.listOfPersons on s.Id equals p.StoreId
               group c by c.Name into newGroup
               select newGroup );
```

I need to add the number of employees but I don`t have any idea how to add that counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result2 = (from c in NoOfEntities.listOfCompanies
                join s in NoOfEntities.listOfStores on c.Id equals s.CompanyId
                join p in NoOfEntities.listOfPersons on s.Id equals p.StoreId
                group p by c.Name into newGroup
                select new
                {
                    CompanyName = newGroup.Key,
                    NumberOfEmployees = newGroup.Count()
                });
```